# jquery how to get textbox value inside span element

Tags: jquery, textfield, html

I want to get the value of textfield(only one) inside span element using jquery but couldn't.

```
<span>simple span text
<a class="remove" href="javascript:" title="Remove">x</a>
<input type="hidden" name="word[ids][]" value="this is text">
</span>
```

Jquery code associated to *remove class* of anchor tag

```
$(".remove").live("click", function(){

alert ($(this).parent().('input:text').val()); // return undefined

//i just coded below to check whether span itself is getting or not
alert ($(this).parent().attr('tag')); // this also return undefined 

if ($(this).parent().is('span'));
alert("parent is span"); // only this works 

});
```

Comment: Oops.... misunderstood the question, nvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `input` is always the next sibling of the `remove` element, then this will work:

```
$(".remove").live("click", function(){
    var value = $(this).next().val();
});
```

---

Explanation of why your code does not work:

This line `$(this).parent().('input:text').val()` is syntactically and logically wrong.

If you want to find an element inside another one, you have to use [`find` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).parent().find('input:text').val()
```

This will still not give you the value, because you have a *hidden* `input` element. If you have a look at the [`:text` *<sup>[docs]</sup>* documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/), you will see that this selector thus not select those. So either just use `'input'` or use [`:hidden` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/): `'input:hidden'`.

`.attr('tag')` simply does not work because an HTML element has no attribute *tag*. You can get the tag name from the the DOM element using the `nodeName` property:

```
$(this).parent()[0].nodeName
```

Comment: the question asks for a hidden input, not a textbox

Comment: @Edgar: `next()` does not care what type of element it is. The other part is actually to just point out the syntactical errors, but maybe I should clarify a bit more...

Comment: @Felix Kling this one is simplest among other answer. And even no need to worry about whether input type is text or hidden.Thanks for additional info.

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```
 $(".remove").live("click", function() {
    //alert($(this).parent().attr('tagName')); //return the tagName
    alert($(this).parent().find('input').val()); //this works
});
```

Test it here http://jsfiddle.net/zhiyelee/29bgX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".remove").live("click", function() {
    alert ($(this).parent().find("input").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
$(this).parent().('input:text').val()
```

Instead, you would need to use the `find` function. Another problem is the fact that you are looking for a text input, but your input is of type `hidden`:

```
$(this).parent().find('input:hidden').val()
```

On a separate note, your final `alert` will always be alerted, whether the parent is a `span` or not, because you have a semi-colon at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: thanks for clue about hidden field and semicolon mistake I could have think about that way.Your code also works.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
$(".remove").live("click", function() {
    alert ($(this).closest("span").find("input[type='hidden']").val());
});
```

This will find inside the closest `span` antecessor, so will be more flexible to HTML code changes.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @ Edgar although I stick to Felix Kling's code, I will make note about your flexibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.remove').live('click',
function() {
    console.log($(this).next('input:hidden').val());
});
```